# Describe the language generated?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm currently doing work on discrete mathematics in my free time and am having some difficulties with understanding some questions pertaining to Languages and Functions. To be specific, I'm stuck on the following practice question:

```
Describe the language generated by the grammar G = {Σ, ∆, S, Π}, where
    Σ = {0, 1}, ∆ = {S, X, Y, Z}
and
    Π = {S → 0X|1Y, X → 1Y |1Z, Y → 0X|0Z, Z → 0|e}.
```

I don't really understand how to do language based problems etc., how would I find the resulting language? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any derivation from $S$ will start with either $0X$ or $1Y$. Suppose that it starts with $0X$; what can happen then?

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
0X&\Longrightarrow&01Y&\Longrightarrow&010X&\Longrightarrow&0101Y&\Longrightarrow&\ldots\\
\Downarrow&&\Downarrow&&\Downarrow&&\Downarrow\\
01Z&\Longrightarrow&010Z&\Longrightarrow&0101Z&\Longrightarrow&01010Z&\Longrightarrow&\ldots\\
\Downarrow&&\Downarrow&&\Downarrow&&\Downarrow\\
01\text{ or }010&&010\text{ or }0100&&0101\text{ or }01010&&01010\text{ or }010100&&\ldots
\end{array}$$

Every terminal word that can be derived from $0X$ appears in that bottom row, and it’s not too hard to work out that the bottom row contains exactly the words that begin with $01$, alternate $0$s and $1$s, and then optionally add a final $0$ if the alternating string ends in $0$.

Now see if you can carry out a similar analysis of the case in which the derivations starts with $1Y$; once you have that, putting the two possibilities together gives you a full description of the language.